# How can I override the vendor-dir for a single package in composer.json

Tags: git, composer-php, typo3-flow

I'm bundling a web application through composer. In my config section, a vendor dir needed by the framework (TYPO3 Flow) is defined:

```
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "Packages/Libraries",
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
```

Now I have one custom package that doesn't come from Packagist but from Github. This package needs to be checked out to Packages/Application/Vendor.PackageName. So I tried using the target-dir:

```
"repositories": [{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "version": "dev-master",
        "name": "vendor/package",
        "source": {
            "url": "https://github.com/mycompany/mypackagerepo.git",
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "master"
        },
        "target-dir": "Packages/Application/Vendor.Package",
    }
}],
"require": {
    "typo3/flow": "2.0.*",
    "vendor/package": "dev-master"
}
```

Cloning from Github works fine, but the package is now checked out to

```
Packages/Libraries/vendor/package/Packages/Application/Vendor.Package
```

That means that vendor-dir and target-dir were concatenated.

How is it possible to override the vendor-dir completely for a single package? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `target-dir` you need to use [Composer Installers](https://github.com/composer/installers#a-multi-framework-composer-library-installer) and change the package type to `typo3-flow-package`, so your package definition can be:

```
"repositories": [{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "version": "dev-master",
        "name": "vendor/package",
        "type": "typo3-flow-package",  
        "source": {
            "url": "https://github.com/mycompany/mypackagerepo.git",
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "master"
        },
        "require": {
            "composer/installers": "~1.0"
        }
    }
]}
```

By default your package will be installed under `Packages/Application/package`, but if you want to prefix the package folder with vendor name and get it under `Packages/Application/vendor.package` just add:

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "Packages/Application/{$vendor}.{$name}/": ["type:typo3-flow-package"]
    }
}
```